# Add custom attributes to PlotCurveItem in pyqtgraph

Tags: pyqt, pyqtgraph

I have several curves on one PlotItem. I add them through method plot(). So each of them is a PlotCurveItem instance.

I would like to add additional information to certain curve in order to click on any it and get attribute. Moreover, I want to get attribure that corresponds to x,y of this curve.

Any ideas?